# Uncheck the Checkbox makes no difference

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am doing a bar chart with Javascript D3. I want to sort the data when the checkbox is checked, and when the checkbox is unchecked, the visualization goes back to the unsorted state. 
Now "sorting data when checkbox is checked" works well, but unchecking the checkbox makes no difference (which means the data still stay sorted). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Code snippet:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="sortData(this);" value="sort">Sort Data</label>
</form>

<script>
var data;
function sortData(cb) {
  if (cb.checked) {
    // sort data
    var checkedData = data;
    checkedData.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a[myCategory], b[myCategory]));
    drawVis(checkedData);
  } else {
    // do not sort data
    console.log("Unchecked!");
    drawVis(data);
  }
}

function drawVis(data) {
  svg.selectAll(".bar").remove();
  svg.selectAll("g").remove();
  ......
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("rect");
  ......
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you assigning value to `data` ??

Comment: @Ayush I have values assigned to 'data', but I omitted that part in this code snippet. When the checkbox is checked, it will sort the bars. I am not sure but I don't think the problem lies with the 'data' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here has to do with the fact that *you think* that you're cloning the `data` array in this line:

```
var checkedData = data;
```

However, you're not. So, when later you do:

```
drawVis(data);
```

This `data` array is the sorted array.

In short, `checkedData` only points to `data`, it's not a different array. Thus, any change you make in one of them changes the other.

Let's show this in a running snippet. I'll sort `fakeCopy`, but `data` also changes:

```js
var data = [3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 0, 1, 4, 8];
var fakeCopy = data;
fakeCopy.sort();
console.log(data);
```

**Solution**: To really clone your `data` array, do this:

```
 var checkedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

That way, whatever you do with `checkedData`, you keep `data` unchanged.

PS: This solution to clone an array using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))` doesn't work if you have dates in it. If that's your case, simply search "JavaScript deep copy" and you're gonna find several different approaches.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo! Your solution really helps a lot. I didn't realize that Javascript also has this deep copy issue! I am new to Javascript but I learned deep copy when I was working with Java.